# Heroku Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch can not be solve by add procfile or add PORT||

Tags: node.js, heroku

Is anyone can save me?
I try to recurrence jseverywhere project but found it does not work in the heroku
I have my first node.js app (runs fine locally) - but I am unable to deploy it via heroku (first time w/ heroku as well). The code is below. SO doesn't let me write so much code, so I would just say that the running the code locally as well within my network shows no issue.
this is my index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-express');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const cors = require('cors');
const depthLimit = require('graphql-depth-limit');
const { createComplexityLimitRule } = require('graphql-validation-complexity');
require('dotenv').config();

const db = require('./db');
const models = require('./models');
const typeDefs = require('./schema');
const resolvers = require('./resolvers');

// Run our server on a port specified in our .env file or port 4000
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const DB_HOST = process.env.DB_HOST;

const app = express();

db.connect(DB_HOST);

app.use(helmet());
app.use(cors());

// get the user info from a JWT
const getUser = token => {
  if (token) {
    try {
      // return the user information from the token
      return jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    } catch (err) {
      // if there's a problem with the token, throw an error
      throw new Error('Session invalid');
    }
  }
};

// Apollo Server setup
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  validationRules:[depthLimit(5),createComplexityLimitRule(1000)],
  context: ({ req }) => {
    // get the user token from the headers
    const token = req.headers.authorization;
    // try to retrieve a user with the token
    const user = getUser(token);
    // add the db models and the user to the context
    return { models, user };
  }
});

// Apply the Apollo GraphQL middleware and set the path to /api
server.applyMiddleware({ app, path: '/api' });

app.listen({ port }, () =>
  console.log(
    `GraphQL Server running at http://localhost:${port}${server.graphqlPath}`
  )
);
```

here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "notedly-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "API code examples for JavaScript Everywhere by Adam Scott, published by O'Reilly Media",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon src/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon src/index.js",
    "final": "nodemon final/index.js",
    "seed": "node final/util/seed/index.js",
    "lint": "eslint \"src/**/*.js\""
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@github.com:javascripteverywhere/api.git"
  },
  "nodemonConfig": {
    "ignore": [
      "**.test.js"
    ]
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Adam Scott",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-server-express": "2.4.0",
    "bcrypt": "3.0.6",
    "cors": "2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "6.1.0",
    "express": "4.16.4",
    "express-session": "1.15.6",
    "graphql": "^14.1.1",
    "graphql-depth-limit": "1.1.0",
    "graphql-iso-date": "3.6.1",
    "graphql-validation-complexity": "0.2.4",
    "helmet": "3.21.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "8.5.1",
    "marked": "0.7.0",
    "md5": "2.2.1",
    "mongoose": "5.7.13",
    "nodemon": "1.18.7",
    "passport": "0.4.0",
    "passport-github2": "0.1.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "5.13.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.0.1",
    "faker": "4.1.0",
    "node-fetch": "2.5.0",
    "prettier": "1.18.2"
  }
}
```

and this is my procfile
I wanna to know how to solve this probelm? this can not be sloved by add procfile or add PORT||

I founnd the log changed like this:

```
2022-07-20T10:30:35.289177+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-07-20T10:30:35.477651+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] 1.18.7
2022-07-20T10:30:35.478244+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
2022-07-20T10:30:35.478500+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] watching: *.*
2022-07-20T10:30:35.478780+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] starting `node src/index.js`
2022-07-20T10:30:35.536250+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
2022-07-20T10:31:33.999623+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2022-07-20T10:31:34.078393+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2022-07-20T10:31:34.101067+00:00 app[web.1]: Error waiting for process to terminate: No child processes
2022-07-20T10:31:34.233354+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 22
2022-07-20T10:31:34.334941+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-07-20T10:31:34.345933+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-07-20T10:31:36.812451+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-07-20T10:31:38.567037+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-07-20T10:31:38.567050+00:00 app[web.1]: > notedly-api@1.0.0 start
2022-07-20T10:31:38.567050+00:00 app[web.1]: > nodemon src/index.js
2022-07-20T10:31:38.567051+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-07-20T10:31:38.843306+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] 1.18.7
2022-07-20T10:31:38.843976+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
2022-07-20T10:31:38.844272+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] watching: *.*
2022-07-20T10:31:38.844607+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] starting `node src/index.js`
2022-07-20T10:31:38.915491+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
2022-07-20T10:32:37.223842+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2022-07-20T10:32:37.276213+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2022-07-20T10:32:37.296604+00:00 app[web.1]: Error waiting for process to terminate: No child processes
2022-07-20T10:32:37.413246+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 22
2022-07-20T10:32:37.457958+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-07-20T10:33:37.810216+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `console` by user yitian2018123@gmail.com
2022-07-20T10:33:40.478704+00:00 heroku[run.5437]: Awaiting client
2022-07-20T10:33:40.494537+00:00 heroku[run.5437]: Starting process with command `console`
2022-07-20T10:33:40.584796+00:00 heroku[run.5437]: State changed from starting to up
2022-07-20T10:33:43.793853+00:00 heroku[run.5437]: Process exited with status 127
2022-07-20T10:33:43.849031+00:00 heroku[run.5437]: State changed from up to complete
2022-07-20T11:14:09.479529+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-07-20T11:14:11.947238+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-07-20T11:14:13.659860+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-07-20T11:14:13.659874+00:00 app[web.1]: > notedly-api@1.0.0 start
2022-07-20T11:14:13.659874+00:00 app[web.1]: > nodemon src/index.js
2022-07-20T11:14:13.659875+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-07-20T11:14:13.829286+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] 1.18.7
2022-07-20T11:14:13.829944+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
2022-07-20T11:14:13.830254+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] watching: *.*
2022-07-20T11:14:13.830541+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] starting `node src/index.js`
2022-07-20T11:14:13.888399+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
2022-07-20T11:15:12.244771+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2022-07-20T11:15:12.288792+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2022-07-20T11:15:12.432666+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2022-07-20T11:15:12.490240+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-07-20T14:30:12.631408+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-07-20T14:30:15.020123+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-07-20T14:30:16.631122+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-07-20T14:30:16.631137+00:00 app[web.1]: > notedly-api@1.0.0 start
2022-07-20T14:30:16.631137+00:00 app[web.1]: > nodemon src/index.js
2022-07-20T14:30:16.631138+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-07-20T14:30:16.799856+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] 1.18.7
2022-07-20T14:30:16.800418+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
2022-07-20T14:30:16.800681+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] watching: *.*
2022-07-20T14:30:16.800965+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] starting `node src/index.js`
2022-07-20T14:30:16.858248+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
2022-07-20T14:31:15.661307+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2022-07-20T14:31:15.710701+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2022-07-20T14:31:15.725011+00:00 app[web.1]: Error waiting for process to terminate: No child processes
2022-07-20T14:31:15.879571+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 22
2022-07-20T14:31:15.977496+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-07-20T19:33:21.266559+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-07-20T19:33:23.547545+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-07-20T19:33:25.163020+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-07-20T19:33:25.163034+00:00 app[web.1]: > notedly-api@1.0.0 start
2022-07-20T19:33:25.163034+00:00 app[web.1]: > nodemon src/index.js
2022-07-20T19:33:25.163035+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-07-20T19:33:25.326132+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] 1.18.7
2022-07-20T19:33:25.326435+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
2022-07-20T19:33:25.326682+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] watching: *.*
2022-07-20T19:33:25.326948+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] starting `node src/index.js`
2022-07-20T19:33:25.379634+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
2022-07-20T19:34:24.094016+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2022-07-20T19:34:24.196102+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2022-07-20T19:34:24.269207+00:00 app[web.1]: Error waiting for process to terminate: No child processes
2022-07-20T19:34:24.397123+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 22
2022-07-20T19:34:24.470313+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-07-21T00:31:31.350115+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tylortianjsapi.herokuapp.com request_id=af469142-840e-4247-9b96-d9ce06f66b8c fwd="51.79.145.192" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-21T00:32:02.167382+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=tylortianjsapi.herokuapp.com request_id=27adcb9e-560a-48d5-9b4e-fbbb9c04bda8 fwd="51.79.220.122" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-21T00:32:11.689691+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tylortianjsapi.herokuapp.com request_id=929b4cf1-ffd8-44be-84d7-060de9965e73 fwd="51.79.145.174" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-21T00:33:17.635376+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=tylortianjsapi.herokuapp.com request_id=ab2695b1-2757-486a-8afb-578eb00c09b9 fwd="51.79.220.231" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-21T00:53:03.536382+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tylortianjsapi.herokuapp.com request_id=f1997972-eff7-4502-bc75-4389e5d86f38 fwd="51.79.145.192" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-21T00:53:04.748965+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=tylortianjsapi.herokuapp.com request_id=6ece6fb3-f6cf-4372-9f34-f7ed1b67bb21 fwd="51.79.145.224" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-21T00:56:57.655945+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@0:Free by user yitian2018123@gmail.com
2022-07-21T00:57:14.032291+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to down
2022-07-21T04:06:24.207475+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tylortianjsapi.herokuapp.com request_id=640ebe61-c892-4255-a8b9-550e0a309d28 fwd="210.22.150.146" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-21T04:06:24.744505+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=tylortianjsapi.herokuapp.com request_id=318b76bf-0944-4ddb-b1eb-ca611bb070f4 fwd="210.22.150.146" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-21T04:06:25.269372+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tylortianjsapi.herokuapp.com request_id=ab61926d-1a8f-4767-bdaf-8bdf18334998 fwd="123.158.49.167" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-21T04:06:27.234518+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/1" host=tylortianjsapi.herokuapp.com request_id=e11a22a2-9a0c-40d6-86dc-485789d999b7 fwd="110.177.176.142" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-21T04:06:27.453451+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tylortianjsapi.herokuapp.com request_id=8ecf61b1-9173-45ec-8950-d434a633fafa fwd="118.81.7.115" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-21T04:06:35.618913+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/1" host=tylortianjsapi.herokuapp.com request_id=173724d6-0a4c-497f-83b6-c807525da993 fwd="36.32.2.58" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-21T04:06:37.607235+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tylortianjsapi.herokuapp.com request_id=e12870d9-d800-450a-a2c2-bf5445705df9 fwd="110.177.177.182" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2022-07-21T04:06:39.362692+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tylortianjsapi.herokuapp.com request_id=8086d373-fe55-41ff-9a35-071153adfcd2 fwd="111.85.200.148" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2022-07-21T04:06:50.543481+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/1" host=tylortianjsapi.herokuapp.com request_id=92404eb9-d97e-4f08-b8a4-f6b89596b3ee fwd="144.255.31.217" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2022-07-21T13:53:03.993885+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tylortianjsapi.herokuapp.com request_id=78ab6887-c992-44c5-8537-b5888a471cb0 fwd="51.79.220.122" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-21T13:53:05.099185+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=tylortianjsapi.herokuapp.com request_id=db004a6a-a8b4-4bed-bfe8-393f03059582 fwd="51.79.145.192" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: It's good you are referring to the `port` `const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;` and using it. However it fails to bind to it `Web process failed to bind to $PORT`. The problem can be manifold. Either your installation of the dependencies were faulty -> provide full build log. And/or during execution of your project there was an error -> provide full log the moment you enable the web process.

Comment: I found the log error changed...

Comment: I just add the log onn the original question >_<

Comment: Is src/index.html empty? Because here it is https://github.com/javascripteverywhere/api/blob/master/src/index.js Did you put it in final/index.html because content there is identical to your code here https://github.com/javascripteverywhere/api/blob/master/final/index.js. If you look at `nodemon src/index.js` and if this is the case here it is executing nothing and thus fails.

Comment: actually my index.js is like final/index.js

Comment: actually my index.js is like final/index.js